# Using compressed prepopulated database with room

Tags: android-room

I have a compressed database with [sqlite_zstd](https://github.com/phiresky/sqlite-zstd) which i would like to use in an android app with room database.

knowing the shipped version of sqlite in android doesn't support extensions, [requery/sqlite_android](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) was used to load the extension for sqlite_zstd.

the challenge

the database tables do not remain the same after compression and the column types do not match when i use it as a pre-packaged database for room

the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Dictionary(com.ayitinya.englishdictionary.data.test.LocalTest).
                                                                                                     Expected:
                                                                                                    TableInfo{name='Dictionary', columns={data=Column{name='data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
                                                                                                     Found:
                                                                                                    TableInfo{name='Dictionary', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, data=Column{name='data', type='', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "Dictionary")
data class LocalTest(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val wordId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "data") val word: String,
)
```

the command i use to create the database in python as i am looping over json, removing what isn't wanted and storing it in a database for read only

```py
 cursor.execute(
        """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dictionary (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                data TEXT NOT NULL
            )
        """
    )

...

   cursor.execute(f'SELECT zstd_enable_transparent(\'{{"table": "Dictionary", "column": "data", "compression_level": 19, "dict_chooser": "\'\'a\'\' || (id / 1000000)"}}\');')
    cursor.execute("SELECT zstd_incremental_maintenance(null, 1)")
    cursor. Execute("VACUUM")

...
```

the first question

Why does room show my primary key (id) as nullable when the database is created with NOT NULL on id

and the second

how do i match the database schema from room with the prepopulated one, as i have no control over the schema after the compression is done

Edit:

[image: A screenshot of the information produced from a sqlite tool]

Answer (score 1):

> Why does room show my primary key (id) as nullable when the database is created with NOT NULL on id

Unsure but using Room libraries 2.5.2 and **kapt** using your LocalTest class asis, then Room generates (***and thus EXPECTS***)the following:-

```
_db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dictionary` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `data` TEXT NOT NULL)");
```

- this reflects what Room **expects**
- The above is found in the **createAllTables** function of the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl** that is in the java(generated). Visible via the **Android View**

However, the actual issue the message is pointing out is that Room **expects**

1. the **data** column to have the **`NOT NULL`** constraint., and
2. That the **id** column to be the PRIMARY KEY.

Splitting the message into the columns and comparing show (expected followed by found):-

```
name='data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
name='data', type='', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
```

- i.e. the **data** column according to Room should have the NOT NULL constraint. However the **data** column found is nullable.

and:-

```
name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'
name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
```

- i.e. The **id** column is not part of the PRIMARY KEY

At a guess, the actual database, is not created according to your CREATE statement (does it already exist???). A suggestion would be to use an SQLite tool to look at the actual database file that is being packaged.

> how do i match the database schema from room with the prepopulated one, as i have no control over the schema after the compression is done

The **`prePackagedDatabase`** callback could be utilised to convert the database (i.e. create the table as expected and load it from the non-compliant table).

***More to follow***

---

**DEMO** (ignoring compression/decompression)

---

First an SQLite tool (Navicat for SQLite) was used to create a database in inline with the non-compliant **FOUND** database loading it  with some data using the following SQL:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dictionary (
    id INTEGER /*????????? PRIMARY KEY, AUTOINCREMENT and NOT NULL OMITTED*/,
    data TEXT /*?????????? NOT NULL OMITTED */
);
INSERT INTO dictionary VALUES
    (1,'Word001'),(100,'Word100'),(4,'WORD004'),(4 /*OOOPS NOT UNIQUE ID*/,'WORD005') /* etc */
;
```

- see comments

The database/connection and Navicat itself were closed (so that the -wal files were committed/checkpointed)

- not committing/checkpointing and copying just the single file could   result in the database not appearing to match.

The file was then copied as an asset and run WITHOUT the prePackagedDatabase callback. Resulting in (as expected):-

```
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='Dictionary', columns={data=Column{name='data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='Dictionary', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, data=Column{name='data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

- i.e. issues between the **expected** and **not found** (similar but not exactly to the original issue *(again unsure about NOT NULL false for the expected **id** column)*).

***Introduction of the PrePackagedDatabase Callback***

- note that this was initially used BUT with the callback commented out (hence previous error above)

The `@Database` annotated class with PrePackagedDatabase call back to modify/correct the database maintaining the data (except the duplicated id):-

```
@Database(entities = [LocalTest::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        private val TAG = "PPDOPEN"
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* FOR BREVITY OF DEMO */
                    .createFromAsset("the_database.db_asset",pdc/*<<<<<<<<<<,pdc COMMENTED OUT INITIALLY*/)
                    .build()
            }
            /* WANTED?????????? */
            /* THIS WILL FORCE DATABASE OPEN AN THUS CREATION FROM ASSET AND THUS CALLBACK TO CONVERT DATABASE */
            instance!!.openHelper.writableDatabase
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        private val pdc = object: PrepackagedDatabaseCallback(){

            val renameExtension = "_renamed"
            val actualDictionaryTableName = "Dictionary"
            val originalTableName = "${actualDictionaryTableName}${renameExtension}"
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /*>>>>>>>>>> AS COPIED FROM Java(generated) createAllTables function <<<<<<<<<<*/
            val roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dictionary` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `data` TEXT NOT NULL)"
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            override fun onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db)
                Log.d(TAG,"Prepackaged Database has been copied and opened")
                showSchema(db,"_STG1")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG2")
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE $actualDictionaryTableName RENAME TO $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG3")
                db.execSQL(roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition)
                showSchema(db,"STG4")
                /* AS LONG AS THE COLUMNS EXIST then should work irrespective of the SCHEMA differences */
                /* !!!!NOTE!!!! OR IGNORE may not be suitable as it assumes it is OK to drop duplicate ids */
                db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $actualDictionaryTableName SELECT id,data FROM $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG5")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $originalTableName") /* not required but probably wanted */
                showSchema(db,"STG6")
                db.execSQL("VACUUM") /* not required but probably wanted */
            }
        }
        /* could be used for debugging if immediate return removed*/
        fun showSchema(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,suffix: String) {
            return
            Log.d(TAG + suffix,"SCHEMA IS:-")
            val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
            csr.close()
        }
    }
}
```

- **purposefully a bit OTT**
- see the comments, especially in regard to copying the SQL from the generated java aka the **expected** schema

  - the schema of the asset can be quite different, as long as the table itself exists and that the columns exist (although the expected constraints could prove to result in issues)

This results in a successful run with App Inspection showing:-

[image]

- noting that the rogue WORD005 (id 4 duplicated) has been IGNOREd

---

**ADDITIONAL**

---

With the revelation that it very much appears that Room has considered the **View** as a table and the additional schema of the asset then it may be best to pre-prepare the database before room itself opens the database, as the ***requery*** library needs to be utilised to ***decompress*** the database. This methodology would also circumvent issues that may arise due to locks and transactions wrapped around the PrePacakagedDatabase callback.

- is there a significant reduction in the size of the package (packages are zipped). If not then bypassing the compression and subsequent need to decompress would be simpler.

As such the process would be:-

1. check if the database exists, if so do nothing more, otherwise then,
2. check if the parent folder exists, to cover early Android versions, if not the to make the directories (using mkDirs()), then
3. copy the asset into the directory, then
4. open the database using the ***requery API***
5. drop the view (as it uses the same name as the table and Room appears to not distinguish between view and table, it is also not needed)
6. create the dictionary table using the SQL copied from the generated java i.e. as per Room's expectations
7. load the table with the data decompression it, i.e. use the query as per the view to insert the data
8. optionally (but suggested), clean up the database by removing the defunct components and finally VACUUM the database

- noting that the ***requery API*** (assuming that it permits use of all the above) should be used

  - if the ***requery API*** is insufficient, then the database could be closed and the opened using the standard SQLiteDatabase API

Here's the code (***untested*** so an in principle guide) amended to (note that the PrePackagedDatabase callback has not been removed, also in theory the `createFromAsset` method would not be invoked as the database should exist as it has bee pre-prepared):-

```
@Database(entities = [LocalTest::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        private val TAG = "PPDOPEN"
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
            /*<<<<<<<<<< PRE-PREPARE DATABASE (copy asset and decompress dictionary table) >>>>>>>>>>*/
            /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
            retrievePackagedDatabaseIfRequired(context,"the_database.db","the_database.db_asset")
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* FOR BREVITY OF DEMO */
                    .createFromAsset("the_database.db_asset",pdc/*<<<<<<<<<<,pdc COMMENTED OUT INITIALLY*/)
                    .build()
            }
            /* WANTED?????????? */
            /* THIS WILL FORCE DATABASE OPEN AN THUS CREATION FROM ASSET AND THUS CALLBACK TO CONVERT DATABASE */
            instance!!.openHelper.writableDatabase
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        private val pdc = object: PrepackagedDatabaseCallback(){

            val renameExtension = "_renamed"
            val actualDictionaryTableName = "Dictionary"
            val originalTableName = "${actualDictionaryTableName}${renameExtension}"
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            /*>>>>>>>>>> AS COPIED FROM Java(generated) createAllTables function <<<<<<<<<<*/
            val roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Dictionary` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `data` TEXT NOT NULL)"
            /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            override fun onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db)
                Log.d(TAG,"Prepackaged Database has been copied and opened")
                showSchema(db,"_STG1")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG2")
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE $actualDictionaryTableName RENAME TO $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG3")
                db.execSQL(roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition)
                showSchema(db,"STG4")
                /* AS LONG AS THE COLUMNS EXIST then should work irrespective of the SCHEMA differences */
                /* !!!!NOTE!!!! OR IGNORE may not be suitable as it assumes it is OK to drop duplicate ids */
                db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $actualDictionaryTableName SELECT id,data FROM $originalTableName")
                showSchema(db,"STG5")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $originalTableName") /* not required but probably wanted */
                showSchema(db,"STG6")
                db.execSQL("VACUUM") /* not required but probably wanted */
            }
        }
        /* could be used for debugging if immediate return removed*/
        fun showSchema(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,suffix: String) {
            return
            Log.d(TAG + suffix,"SCHEMA IS:-")
            val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
            csr.close()
        }

        fun retrievePackagedDatabaseIfRequired(context: Context, databaseName: String, assetName: String) {
            val assetInputStream = context.assets.open(assetName)
            val coreZSTDTable = "_Dictionary_zstd"
            val configZSTDTable = "_zstd_configs"
            val dictsZSTDTable = "_zstd_dicts"
            val dictionaryTableName = "dictionary"
            val _dbfile = File(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).path)
            val roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${dictionaryTableName}` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `data` TEXT NOT NULL)"
            val roomDictionaryLoadDataSQL = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ${dictionaryTableName} SELECT `id`,zstd_decompress_col(`data`,1,_data_dict) AS data FROM `${coreZSTDTable}`"

            if (_dbfile.exists()) return
            /* Database does not exist, so check of the parent (directory) exists: if not create the directory*/
            if (!_dbfile.parentFile.exists()) {
                _dbfile.parentFile.mkdirs()
            }
            /* Handle copying and then converting the asset */
            assetInputStream.copyTo(_dbfile.outputStream())
            /*!!!!!!!!!! USE REQUERY SQLiteDatabase, rather than STOCK API SQLiteDatabase !!!!!!!!!!*/
            val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(_dbfile.path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
            db.beginTransaction()
            /*
                Note as testing was done with asset used to test prepackageddatabase callback
                the view does not exists BUT the table does, and thus an exception as per:-
                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: use DROP TABLE to delete table Dictionary (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , 
                    while compiling: DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dictionary
                    
                hence the try/catch to skip this
             */
            try {
                db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ${dictionaryTableName}") /* don't want the view to interfere */

            } catch(e: SQLiteException) {}
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${dictionaryTableName}") /* just in case */
            db.execSQL(roomDictionaryExpectedDefinition) /* Create the table according to Room's expectations */
            db.execSQL(roomDictionaryLoadDataSQL)
            /* CleanUP*/
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${dictsZSTDTable}")
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${configZSTDTable}")
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${coreZSTDTable}")
            db.setTransactionSuccessful()
            db.endTransaction()
            db.execSQL("VACUUM")
            db.close()
        }
    }
}
```

- as can be seen from the comments some limited testing has been undertaken (hence the try/catch to get around the view/table disparity)l i.e. the above works as far as the loading of the data, so **it does not test the use of the *requery* lib/API**

  - commenting out the load data line and the App works fine and results in [image] (no data as the load was skipped, but the table meets Room's expectations).

Comment: That's a very elaborate answer. I would give it a try, but I've attached a screen grab of information a sqlite tool (DB browser for sqlite, linux) gives. Apparently, sqlite_zstd creates a view of the table after compression

Comment: @ayitinya the view appears to be what has been considered the table. At a **guess** the core but compressed data is held in the data column of the dictionary_zstd table. The view is used to decompress the data via the zstd extension. As such the conversion is going to be more complicated as you will need to access to the request SQLiteDatabase (i.e. to initially not utilse room). I would suggest that it is safer to bypass Room's PrePackagedDatabase callback and instead control the process. Will look at adding the basics of doing so to the answer.

Comment: @ayitinya answer updated with a ***PrePrepare*** example.

Comment: I ended creating tables to match the tables generated from sqlite_zstd, our timezones seem to be eternity apart

Comment: I now have a situation where the data from the asset is not fully loaded when trying to access it. What I have done is to read from the database when the app loads for the first time, but when the data user tries to access the data faster than the copy process is completed it leads to the app crashing with "non null is null error"

Comment: do I open a new question?