# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema in Room Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-room, database-migration

I am trying to get data from the asset folder SQL DB but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: recipetype(com.example.finddishrecipe.room.RecipeEntity).
Expected:
TableInfo{name='recipetype', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, image=Column{name='image', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='recipetype', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, image=Column{name='image', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

This is my entity code:

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipetype")

data class RecipeEntity(
    @PrimaryKey

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    val image: String
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960555/20755786 - assuming order of columns in the asset file, please provide it too.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "recipetype" (
 "id" INTEGER,
 "name" TEXT,
 "image" TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the columns are supposed to have non null constraints according to expected schema. Define them as non null values while creating the table by adding `NOT NULL` constraint as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "recipetype" ( "id" INTEGER NOT NULL, "name" TEXT NOT NULL, "image" TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT) )
```

Or you can make entity class columns as nullables.

Order of the columns shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ensure that a prepackaged database matches what Room expects is to:-

1. Create the `@Entity` annotated class(es), then
2. Add the `@Database` annotated class (abstract) with the `@Entity` annotated class(es) defined in the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation, then
3. Successfully compile the project (CTRL +F9).
4. Using the **Android View** locate the java(generated) folder, then
5. Locate the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **Impl**, then
6. Locate the **createAllTables** method, then for each table (`@Entity` annotated class)
7. copy the SQL that Room has generated for the table to create the table in the SQLite Tool you are using.

   1. this SQL is **EXACTLY** what Room **Expects** and hence there is no need to try to predict Room's underlying rules.

- Note ignore room_master table, Room will handle it's creation
- other components, such as Views and Indexes can also be created accordingly as and if required.

If you have an existing database that is relatively close then you can use the SQLite Tool to convert the definitions along the lines of:-

1. **ALTER** the existing table(s) to **RENAME** it(them).
2. **CREATE** the actual table(s) using the SQL from the generated java.
3. Use the renamed original table to load the data into the newly created actual table (often this could be as simple as `INSERT INTO actual_table SELECT * FROM renamed_existing_table` obviously naming the table names accordingly)
4. Optionally **DROP** the renamed table(s)
5. Optionally **VACUUM** the database (to free unused pages)

Alternately, you could use a PrePackagedDatabase callback's overidden `onOpen` method to convert the Database following a similar approach to convert the table(s) when the asset is copied.

- similar to this answer [Using compressed prepopulated database with room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77493447/using-compressed-prepopulated-database-with-room/77498662#77498662)